How to get SSID in react js
I want to try to get the SSID of the WiFi that is currently connected, how do I do it in React JS, has anyone tried it? But in this case, there is no API or Back end that provides get data
Can get the SSID that is currently connected to the device being used

Client-side React? Not possible. Your website has no business knowing what WiFi network I'm connected to.

not only no business knowing, but absolutely no reason to know

Using Electron
If you are building a desktop application with Electron, you can use Node.js packages to get the SSID. Here’s an example using the node-wifi package:

 1. Install the node-wifi package:
 npm install node-wifi
 2. Create an Electron main process script to fetch the SSID:
const { app, BrowserWindow } = require('electron');
const wifi = require('node-wifi');

wifi.init({
  iface: null // network interface, choose a random wifi interface if set to null
});

app.on('ready', () => {
  const win = new BrowserWindow({
    webPreferences: {
      nodeIntegration: true,
      contextIsolation: false
    }
  });

  win.loadURL('http://localhost:3000'); // or the path to your React app

  // Fetch the current SSID
  wifi.getCurrentConnections((error, currentConnections) => {
    if (error) {
      console.log(error);
    } else {
      console.log(currentConnections);
      // Send the SSID to the renderer process
      win.webContents.on('did-finish-load', () => {
        win.webContents.send('ssid', currentConnections[0].ssid);
      });
    }
  });
});

import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
const { ipcRenderer } = window.require('electron');

function App() {
  const [ssid, setSsid] = useState('');

  useEffect(() => {
    ipcRenderer.on('ssid', (event, ssid) => {
      setSsid(ssid);
    });
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Connected SSID: {ssid}</h1>

    </div>
  );
 }

 export default App;


can you explain your answer?

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
